# PHP Function with jquery random insert records by class dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the below function created to display a block with random names. Another array is created to then grab more records and randomly insert them into the tags by class "name" with the fadeIn, fadeOut effect.  All works with the exception of the script actually injecting 'new names' into the li's.

```
    function query_in_memoriam() {

/*authentication call hidden */
$query = "SELECT formatted_name FROM xxxx WHERE xxxx = 'xxxx' ORDER BY RAND(last_name) LIMIT 30";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$i = 0;
$buildMemoriam = "";
while ($i < 20){
    $result_array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $buildMemoriam .= '<li class="name">'.$result_array['formatted_name'].'</li>';
    $i++;
}   

$buildMemoriamDisplay = '<div id="memoriam" class="row bg-standard">
    <h2>In Memoriam </h2>
    <p>In progress, randomizes on refresh, just need to fade in/out names. JA 8/31</p>
    <div id="memoriam-container">
        <ul class="memoriam-items">
        ' . $buildMemoriam . '
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>';

$i = 21;
$array = "";
    while ($i < 30 ){
        $result_array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $array = '"'.$result_array['formatted_name'].'",';
        $i++;
    }
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
var names = [<?php json_encode($array); ?> ];
var lis = document.getElementsByClassName('name');

window.setInterval(function changeNameRandomly() {
  var randomNamesIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
  var randomLiIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * lis.length);
  var randomName = "";
  $(lis[randomLiIndex]).fadeOut("slow", function() {
    randomName = names[randomNamesIndex];
    var addit = true;
    $(".name").each(function()
    {
        if ( $(this).text() == randomName ) {
            // console.log("Duplicate: looking again");
            addit = false;
            $(lis[randomLiIndex]).fadeIn();
        }
     });
     if(addit) {
        $(lis[randomLiIndex]).html(randomName);
        // console.log(randomName);
        $(lis[randomLiIndex]).fadeIn();
     }
  }.bind(this));

}, 2000);
});
</script>
<?php
return $buildMemoriamDisplay;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not making an array you are making a string ... and replacing it each time.  Here is updated code

```
$array = array();
while ($i < 30 ){
     $result_array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     $array[] = $result_array['formatted_name'];
     $i++;
}
```

and this

```
var names = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```